# Phase shifting 2 waveforms to create a rotating magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, phase-shift, electromagnet

I'm trying to set up a rotating magnetic field with 4 electromagnets coils (2 pairs) arranged around a fluidic cell. I have read that you need to shift the 2 waveforms out of phase by 90 degrees to create the rotating field, however I am curious about how to actually do this (I'm new to this, sorry). The function generators I have access to (agilent 33220A) don't seem to be able to let me set the phase or apply a phase shift outside of short burst modulation. Am I going to require new equipment, or is there a way to achieve the phase shift with what I have?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are going to need additional equipment. You function generator has only a single output - you need at least 2 independent outputs on the function generator hence why there are no phase shift/phase delay features. You would also need appropriate coil drivers that go between the FG and the motor coils.

An easier solution would be to use a stepper motor driver which implements all the necessary circuitry to achieve what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Stepper driver is a good idea; another possibility is a VFD (variable frequency drive), if you don't need very high frequency. Though you'll have to look up models that can drive what you're doing (e.g. low voltage or current-limit mode to deal with low inductance coils). Have seen one used to recreate Tesla's "Egg of Columbus" demonstration.

Comment: Oh this isn't for a motor, I am manipulating magnetic nanoparticles with the fields generated in this experiment. I was going to run my FG through an amplifier before I get to the coils to achieve the necessary field strength. Thank you for the info on my FG, I will search for one with 2 outputs

Comment: @LeviB The stepper motor driver still might be your solution. Even you aren't powering a stepper motor because to the stepper motor driver, your load that it sees is exactly the same. You can use you FG to control the rotating field speed. If you need high-resolution control on your field, find one that does "micro-stepping". That will provide you a quasi-continuous rotating field as opposed to discreet "step" field changes.